# How can I force Eclipse to use Sun Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu-10.10

Before installing Eclipse, I had OpenJDK as the default JVM. Recently I changed it to Sun Java.

I did this because Eclipse Helios was running really slow. Unfortunately, it is still slow... Do you have any ideas how to force it to use Sun Java?

I could reinstall Eclipse, however I have already installed the Android SDK, so I would have to install that again. After all, I don't think that's the correct way of solving the problem. I'm using Ubuntu 10.10.

```
$ java -version  
java version "1.6.0_22" 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build1.6.0_22-b04) 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode)
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: If you have similar problem - you are working on Eclipse with Android, and Eclipse is running so slow, firstly check which version are you using. There are some bugs in 3.6 Helios:/ The easiest way is to get e.g. 3.5 ver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell Eclipse which VM to use using `-vm` command line args.

See [Eclipse wiki for example usage](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Launcher#Finding_a_VM.2C_Using_JNI_Invocation_or_Executing_Java)

Comment: thanks that works, I was on Eclipse wiki before however I have not noticed that:/

Answer (score 7):

Edit [`$ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse.ini`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) and add the following before the `vmargs` option.

```
-vm
/opt/path/to/sun-jdk-1.6.0.02/bin/java
```