# Struts2 exclude com.sun:tools:jar:1.5.0 required?

Tags: java, maven, struts2

I am new to Struts2.

Whenever I include the Struts2 dependency, why do I have to do like this?

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>${struts.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

If I don't do this, **Eclipse Juno** gives me error at this point.

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd
```

With this error:

```
Missing artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.5.0
```

Is this the way to do it or is there a better way?

I noticed that this problem happens from version 2.1.6 and higher.

Comment: That is strange, I used Struts 2 on several project, I don't recall having to exclude this com.sun.tools JAR... What version of Struts2 are you using ? Are you using Maven in command line or as an Eclipse/Intellij plugin ?

Comment: @PierreHenry I am using maven plugin. Version below 2.1.6 does not give this error.

Comment: If you build from command line (without the exclude), does it also give you this "Missing artifact" error ?

Comment: You can solve this issue without excluding anything: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19827445/363573

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The artifact `com.sun:tools:jar:1.5.0` is a jar from the JDK (not the JRE). This jar is not available in any maven repository but is located in `<JDK_HOME>/lib`. That's why you get this error.

When you specify an exclusion, maven won't try to find the jar (and so it won't fail).

[Struts2 requires this dependency at compile time](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/struts2-osgi-bundles/dependencies.html) (not at runtime).

So setting an exclusion is the correct way of getting rid of this problem. Since maven need a JDK to run: the tools.jar will be available anyway when compiling the project.

Comment: Setting an exclusion is NOT the correct way ! Check this answer instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19827445/363573

Comment: @Alex I disagree with the linked answer. It's about an eclipse specific problem. The question here is about maven. I my opinion you are missing the most important point : struts needs tools.jar ONLY at compile time !

Comment: @ben75 OP says that the error appears in **Eclipse Juno**. The linked answer gives at least an alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to do this.

That you do indicates there's an issue in your Eclipse, Eclipse project, and/or Eclipse Maven plugin configuration. By way of comparison, I have S2 projects for essentially every version, and in no pom do I need to exclude the Java tools jar, and never have.

Comment: So what sould OP do ? What should be done by debelopers for avoiding this problem ?

Comment: @Alex OP should include more information so people can reproduce the error; I cannot.

Comment: I recently had the same issue, here is how I solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19827445/363573. You'll notice I did without excluding anything ;)

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM EXPLAINED**

Actually, what happens is that struts2 relies on a system dependency, namely `tools.jar`. This dependency is found by resolving this path: `${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar`.

If you compile your project with maven, maven will be clever enough to replace `${java.home}` with the right *JDK* location.

For some reason, if you try to compile your mavenized project with eclipse (ie with m2e help generally), `${java.home}` is resolved against the `-vm` eclipse command line parameter.

**SOLUTION**

If you want to solve this issue, DO NOT exclude the `tools.jar`. Instead force your eclipse to run with your favorite JDK in either of the following ways (*since I don't know your OS, I'll give examples in an OS agnostic form*):

- **Command line switch**

> /path/to/eclipse -vm /path/to/jdk/bin/javaw

Check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1919405/363573) for an example on Windows.

- **eclipse.ini**

> -vm
>       /path/to/jdk/bin/javaw

Check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4706421/363573) for an example on Windows.